# optimizing the code

Tags: sql, database

I have written this code for small database but  know the database size has increased,it is showing timeout error.plz help in optimizing it
Below is the code:-

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Temp_expo') is not null
begin 
    drop table Temp_expo
end

set @query3 =  'SELECT SPCT_ID_REL_LOW,SPCT_ID_REL_HIGH,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by PDBC_PFX) as TempId  

INTO Temp_expo  
FROM ['+ @FCTServer +'].['+@FCTDBName+'].dbo.CMC_SPCT_SUPP_CONV  
where  SPCT_ID_REL_LOW <> '''' and SPCT_ID_REL_HIGH <> '''''

exec (@query3)

Select @minCount= min(TempId) from Temp_expo   
Select @maxCount= max(TempId) from Temp_expo  

create table #ICD9SPCT
(
    ICD9Code varchar(200)
} 

while @minCount<=@maxCount 
begin
    select @low=SPCT_ID_REL_LOW,@high=SPCT_ID_REL_HIGH 
    from Temp_expo 
    where TempId=@minCount 
    group by SPCT_ID_REL_LOW,SPCT_ID_REL_HIGH

    set  @loworder = (select ISNULL(OrderId,0) from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER where ICD9=@low)
    set  @highorder = (select ISNULL(OrderId,0) from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER where ICD9=@high)


    insert into #ICD9SPCT 
    select ICD9 from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER ordert
    left join #ICD9SPCT icdorder on ordert.ICD9 = icdorder.ICD9Code
    where OrderId between @loworder and @highorder and icdorder.ICD9Code is null

    set @minCount = @minCount+1;
end
```

Comment: It's difficult to help you with this as there's no code "we" can work with. It'd help a lot if you could make a working example using something like http://sqlfiddle.com/ - as a quick shot, I'd check whether you have the fields you're referencing appropriately indexed.

Comment: i have to pick the SPCT_ID_REL_LOW,SPCT_ID_REL_HIGH value from the table and keep them in temp table & use it. this LOW,HIGH is range value which is around LAKHS in number.is there any way that i can use it directly by single select statement without using temp table

Answer (score 0):

If this is for SQL SERVER, there are some basic tips you can try:
USE:  WITH (NOLOCK) after every select you use.
i.e.
select ICD9 from FCT_ICD9_Diag_ORDER ordert WITH (NOLOCK)
    left join #ICD9SPCT icdorder on ordert.ICD9 = icdorder.ICD9Code
    where OrderId between @loworder and @highorder and icdorder.ICD9Code is null

You can also try to change your temp tables to variable tables, by just changing the # for an @ like :

create table @ICD9SPCT
(
    ICD9Code varchar(200)
}

Still, the WHILE loop you are  using may be the primary cause of your problem.